# hsqldb call procedure from java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, call, hsqldb

I have created this procedure in hsqldb

```
create procedure insertarUsuario
(nombre varchar(50), apellidos varchar(50), usuariowin varchar(10),xlnet varchar(10), correo varchar(150), planta integer, telefono integer)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO USUARIOS VALUES(nombre, apellidos, usuariowin, xlnet,correo,planta,telefono);
end;
```

from java I call this procedure

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
       ConexionBBDD con = new ConexionBBDD();

```
    String sql = "{call public.insertarUsuario(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

    CallableStatement cs = con.getConnection().prepareCall(sql);

        cs.setString(1, "esto");
        cs.setString(2, "es");
        cs.setString(3, "una");
        cs.setString(4, "prueba");
        cs.setString(5, "insercion");
        cs.setInt(6, 1);
        cs.setInt(7, 2);

        cs.execute();
        cs.close();

        con.desconexionBBDD();  
}
```

but don't working.

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user does not have sufficient privileges or object not found: INSERTARUSUARIO
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
    at ventanas.pruebaConexion.main(pruebaConexion.java:28)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: INSERTARUSUARIO
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readColumnOrFunctionExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileCallStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more`
```

please helpme.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means the database user does not have the privileges to call the procedure. If the PUBLIC user is calling the procedure, this statement grants the privilege. For other users replace PUBLIC with the name of the user.

```
GRANT ALL ON insertarUsuario TO PUBLIC
```

When GRANT fails with "user lacks privilege or object not found", it indicates a path to a different database is being used.

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON my_procedure TO PUBLIC;` gives error message `[SET - 0 rows, 0.002 secs]  [Code: -5501, SQL State: 42501]  user lacks privilege or object not found: MY_PROCEDURE in statement [GRANT ALL ON my_procedure TO PUBLIC]`